# How can I redirect to a specified page after performing a MySQL insert or update?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

After using form data to perform a MySQL update (via PHP), I'd like to direct the user to a page that displays that data as it will appear on the site.

How can I automatically redirect the user to a page (preview.php, for example) AFTER running the MySQL update?

I'd like to keep the solution to HTML or PHP if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has to avoid any output to be able to send the Location [header](http://php.net/header) which redirects the browser. Just avoid any output (echo, var_dump, etc.) and after the insertions have been made, write

```
header("Location: preview.php");
```